# Overloading () operator in C#

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

I have this class called `Lazy` which it whole purpose is to contain a `Func` that takes no arguments and returns a value.

```
public class Lazy<A> {
    Func<A> a;

    public Lazy(A val){
        a = () => val;
    }

    public A operator () ()
    {
        return a();
    }
}
```

As described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985932.aspx), I want to define the `()` operator so I can execute the inner function naturally. But I get this error

> Unexpected symbol `(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

It seems the syntax is wrong. What is the proper way to do it?

Comment: You linked to documentation for **C++**, which supports this. **C#** does not.

Comment: @MichaelLiu thanks! Didn't pay attention to that detail jajajaj

Comment: What you want to use is `delegate`s.

Answer (score 1):

Operators you can overload in c# are:

```
+ - ! ~ ++ -- true false
* / % & | ^ << >> == != > < >= <=
```